# Visited hyperlink background disappears on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have 2 background images that serve as hyperlinks. When I visit any of the hyperlinks on mobile and go back to the page containing the hyperlinks, the visited hyperlink's image disappears. However, the area, where the background image should be, is still clickable.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <a class="div1" href="page1" id="id1">smth</a>
  <a class="div2" href="page2" id="id2">smth</a>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 82%;
  height: 100%;
}

.div1, .div2 {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  height: 16.7vw;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.div1 {
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-image: url('../images/img1.svg');
}

.div2 {
  background-position: 50% 0%;
  background-image: url('../images/img2.svg');
}

.div1:hover {
  background-image: url('../images/img3.svg');
}

.div2:hover {
  background-image: url('../images/img4.svg');
}
```

There seems to be no problem on a computer. I have tested with Chrome and Safari.
My mobile is an iPhone 6S with up-to-date iOS using Safari.

Is there a way to NOT make the background disappear?

Comment: What problem are you facing? It's fine on me. Are you having this error `{"error": "Please use POST request"}`?